# improving volume slider with HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created an simple audio slider (thanks to alot of the answers on here) that auto plays some audio (at zero volume) when the user clicks the slider, and then allows them to increase the volume if they wish.

My only issue is that instead of being a steady increase in volume as the user drags the slider, it only adjusts the volume when they release the slider with the mouse. Is there anyway i can achieve a constant volume adjustment with just the movement of the slider itself. Any help would be much appreciated

JS

```js
var mediaClip;
var volume1;

function init()
{
    mediaClip = document.getElementById("mediaClip");
    volume1 = document.getElementById("volume1");

    mediaClip.play();
}

function setVolume() {
    var mediaClip = document.getElementById("mediaClip");
    mediaClip.volume = document.getElementById("volume1").value;
}


function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("mediaClip");
    audio.play();
}
```

HTML

```html
<body onload="init()">
    <audio id="mediaClip" src="A Very Brady Special.mp3"  style="display:none" allow="autoplay" controls>
        <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
    </audio>

    <input type="range" onchange="setVolume()" id='volume1' min=0 max=1 step=0.01 value='0' onclick="play()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use

```
<input type="range" oninput="setVolume()" id='volume1' min=0 max=1 step=0.01 value='0' onclick="play()">
```

instead of

```
<input type="range" onchange="setVolume()" id='volume1' min=0 max=1 step=0.01 value='0' onclick="play()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Like connexo noted, use `oninput` instead of `onchange`, and I'd use `setVolume(this)` so you can apply it to any slider (and it's neater).

```js
var mediaClip;
var volume1;

function init() {
  mediaClip = document.getElementById("mediaClip");
  volume1 = document.getElementById("volume1");

  mediaClip.play();
}

function setVolume(el) {
  var newVal = el.value;
  
  document.getElementById("volumeVal").innerHTML = newVal;
  mediaClip.volume = newVal;
}


function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("mediaClip");
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">

  <audio id="mediaClip" src="A Very Brady Special.mp3" style="display:none" allow="autoplay" controls>
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
  </audio>

  <p>onChange</p>
  <input type="range" onchange="setVolume(this)" id='volume1' min=0 max=1 step=0.01 value='0' onclick="play()">
  
  <p>onInput</p>
  <input type="range" oninput="setVolume(this)" id='volume1' min=0 max=1 step=0.01 value='0' onclick="play()">
  
  <h3>Volume: <span id="volumeVal">0</span></h3>

</body>
```

Comment: @AlexW No problem, please mark as the answer if it helped =)